# Adding description to WebPartPage when creating the page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, webpartpage

I am following this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms450826.aspx) method to add a webpartpage (samplewpp.aspx) and it works. However, I need to add one line description as well. How?

Comment: Where is the description supposed to be? On the page? In the metadata for the page?

Comment: on the page where the page (samplewpp.aspx) is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) to the page and then add your description to this. The CEWP allows you to put text/html onto a page.

To do this programatically then follow [something like this code by Razi bin Rais](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/3afc6422-7402-4d34-9682-89fa69586813/) :-

```
AddAndFillCEWP("http://server","/" ,"/Pages/blank.aspx","this text is adding via    code","Header","CEWP WebPart");

private void AddAndFillCEWP(string siteUrl, string webName, string pageUrl, string textCEWP, string zoneId, string title)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite spSiteTest = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = spSiteTest.OpenWeb(webName))
            {
                try
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPFile file = web.GetFile(pageUrl);
                    if (null != file)
                    {
                        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                        {
                            if (null != mgr)
                            {
                                //create new webpart object            
                                ContentEditorWebPart contentEditor = new ContentEditorWebPart();

                                //set properties of new webpart object     
                                contentEditor.ZoneID = zoneId;
                                contentEditor.Title = title;
                                contentEditor.ChromeState = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeState.Normal;
                                contentEditor.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.TitleAndBorder;

                                //Add content to CEWP
                                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                                XmlElement xmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Root");
                                xmlElement.InnerText = textCEWP;
                                contentEditor.Content = xmlElement;
                                contentEditor.Content.InnerText = xmlElement.InnerText;

                                //Add it to the zone
                                mgr.AddWebPart(contentEditor, contentEditor.ZoneID, 0);

                                web.Update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```